# Что означает & в сигнатуре метода?

Tags: c++

Есть 2 метода, первый объявлен с && в сигнатуре(тут все ясно, метод можно использовать только у rvalue объектов), второй объявлен с &, и как раз тут не понятно зачем нужна эта ссылка, очень не логично звучит если метод можно использовать только у ссылки на объект

```
   T&& Result() && {
       this->ExceptIfError();
       return std::move(mValue);
    };

    T& Result() & {
        this->ExceptIfError();
        return mValue;
    }
```

Comment: Или вот вычитание... Ну к чему оно, если достаточно унарного минуса? Или унарный минус — можно же просто вычитать из нуля?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ref-квалификатор у метода определяет, какой тип будет у неявно передающегося параметра-ссылки на объект

- квалификатор отсутствует - у параметра будет тип lvalue-ссылка на объект, которая также может биндится к rvalue
- квалификатор `&` - у параметра будет тип lvalue-ссылка на объект, которая не может биндится к rvalue
- квалификатор `&&` - у параметра будет тип rvalue-ссылка на объект, которая биндится только к rvalue

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class Foo
{
    public: void bar1(void) { ::std::cout << "bar1\n"; }
    public: void bar2(void) & { ::std::cout << "bar2\n"; }
    public: void bar3(void) && { ::std::cout << "bar3\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo{};
    foo.bar1(); // ok
    foo.bar2(); // ok
    foo.bar3(); // err
    ::std::move(foo).bar1(); // ok
    ::std::move(foo).bar2(); // err
    ::std::move(foo).bar3(); // ok
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAKykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIAbKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2BASlpGQKh4VEssfFcSXaYDplCBEzEBNk%2BfoHVtQL1jQTFkTFxibYNTS257SO9Yf1lg5UAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMxhyN5YANQmm25OCgTEmKxH2CYaAIJbO3uYh8dejrSEAJ7Xtw/3uyYCgU%2BwAYqhUH8TAB2Kz3fYI/bJLzRT7IED7ABuqDw6H20UaXAg2Nx80OsP2IBAZ3QVLQ71ebiObkOZjMBOIXBM/jcDHMZiOFnJABE/oikSi0RiSXiOWZiTj0GTzAlyUKqTS6csCIzmaz2Y0BTy%2BWzBSKxYjkai8OisYr8Y1NgrSayEiq1ZTqQRaShtbrjvqOZtubz%2BWaYaL7hHBVD7mEdSwmGEIPMobCLQjwah9vxIenoaLNnC7uLcwA6DlE1NF/YAelr%2B1QAGsMzmIRXDSmzfXGy34Yjy0GuzWe3FiK2Nd6qSxUJjMNQIfMO5zh0Ke82J16fTO5wvUEu5au6w2x5vNSAd/PcwfHUf132HgWOItaJx/Lw/BwtKRUJwmZZrH2BRllWF4th4UgCE0Z9FibEBNk2MsEOQlDUKSV8OEkD9oJ/TheAUEANEg6DFjgWAkDQFhkjoOJyEoSjqPoeJgC4NlSCwTEbUwAA1PBMAAdwAeWSRhOAgmhaAIOICIgaIcOiMJGi%2BMTeEothBEEhhaGUr9eCwRMjHEXT2LwC5ajnAjjMwVQanedZv3jTAMO/T5omIJSPCwHDzjwFgVMWKgDGABReIE4TRO4Xh%2BEEEQxHYKQZEERQVHUYzdC4fRDGMaxrH0PBogIyBFlQZJHAESz8Kcmoyr8CBXDGPwMpCaZSnKPRUnSGqGvagoar6Vq5lsKrOgYbpRk8Vo9A6GqxqmEoBgqYYem6jKzh6fqFokRZgJWNYtv0N9sOM38OH2VQAA4EgAWgSSR9mAZBkH2ViyzMfYIFwQgSFZTYuHmXgoN0%2BZYPgxDUPB5D0M4LDSE/b8TvwwjiKB0gyMQEBtWRAg6IgBiaOICJWHWC7rtu%2B7HuesxXt4TB8CIYhcT0aLhFEcQEuZ5K1Bw9LSH49zkn8g6OHfWGcJOwT3ixxsqDOy6bruh6npet6IA8Kj8Z%2Bv6AZIkGEKQiHwaFmG4d4BHbCRwGtGBoWzCO%2BG8ORq3FjnYh0mcSQgA%3D%3D%3D)

Comment: *"`&` ... не может биндится к rvalue"* С `const` - может, как настоящая ссылка.

Answer (score 0):

К переменным можно по-разному обращаться. Можно просто в коде указать, по какому адресу лежат данные. В исходном тексте этому соответствует использование имени, а при компиляции оно будет автоматически заменено адресом из таблицы переменных. Можно вместо этого сказать, что адрес надо взять из другой величины, она называется указатель. А ещё можно этот указатель завернуть так, чтоб он синтаксически не отличался от обычной переменной, а на самом деле из неё будет браться адрес, а уже потом по этому адресу будет происходить обращение в целевой переменной. Это уже возможная реализация ссылки. Нам сейчас не важно, как ссылка реализована, важно другое. Важно, что синтаксически обращение к переменной по ссылке выглядит также, как обращение по дополнительному имени целевой переменной (к которой обращаетесь на самом деле), а при этом подразумевается косвенный доступ (к одной переменной через другую) как по указателю. Так вот, функция (в том числе, функция-член) может вернуть значение, указатель или ссылку. И в случае возврата ссылки нам действительно нужен указатель, синтаксически завёрнутый в ссылку, так как сама переменная известна только Вашей программе, но не тому компилятору, которым она сама компилируется. И адрес её будет получен только при работе функции. Имея же адрес, можно не только взять по нему значение для присваивания переменной или передачи в другую функцию в качестве фактического параметра, но и записать данные по этому адресу в исходном тексте это будет прописано оператором присваивания, в котором функция – левый операнд, а не правый. Мало того, возвращать значения, указатели и ссылки могут ещё и перегруженные операторы (в том числе, операторы члены). Так вот, & перед именем в любой декларации (в том числе, в прототипе функции или оператора) отмечает, что мы декларируем ссылку. В остальных случаях это оператор взятия адреса, то есть, например
`p=&x;`
значит, что переменной p надо присвоить значение не переменной x, а её адреса, после чего p будет указателем именно на x. Теперь можно написать

```
x=2;
```

, а можно –

```
*p=2;
```

, это будет одно и то же. А вот если p – ссылка на x, то оператор * не нужен, а одно и то же значат

```
x=2;
```

и

```
p=2;
```

.

Comment: Здесь же спрашивается про `&` после названия функции-члена, а не про ссылки вообще.